# How can get my 2023 dates to stop acting like 2022 dates in Excel (Pivot Graph)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have my 2022 dec dates as well as my 2023 dates in my table. When I plot it on a Pivot graph, the jan 2023 dates acts like 2022 dates and it comes before my dec 2022 dates. Is there a way I can fix this? I am wondering if it is a Pivot issue. My dates column looks to be good.

[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: How are the cells containing the date formatted?

Comment: It a number format: Date

Comment: Looks like text rather than a date to me - is aligned to the left indicating it's text if you haven't manually aligned it that way.  `=DATEVALUE(A1)` should turn them into dates - first one will return 44920 for the date.